# Reference between play and sbt projects

Tags: scala, sbt

I have one sbt project in this way:

```
root
  - build.sbt
  - project(sbt)
      - Common.scala
  - commons
      - project
      - src...
  - modules
      - clients
         - project
         - src...
         - build.sbt (uses Common.scala)
      - projects
         - project
         - src...
         - build.sbt (uses Common.scala)
  - web(play)
      - build.sbt (uses Common.scala)
      - app
      - conf
      - modules
          - clients
              - app
              - conf
          - projects
              - app
              - conf
```

I have two problems with this structure:

1. If web (the play app) is included as a subproject of root I can start it using sbt "project web" run but the modules within web are not included in the classpath and routes reference to those classes.
2. If web (the play app) is not included in the root project and I start it by itself I don't know how to still using Common.scala to use central dependences in all projects... I can use commons project using the following line but I don't know how to refer to Common.scala in root project, even if I put the Common.scala in the common.

   lazy val common = ProjectRef(uri("../common"),"common")

I would like to know how to handle both situations, or what you recommend me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your build.sbt or scala file?

Comment: The code of the root .sbt, play .sbt and play Build.scala is here http://pastebin.com/ZMQx2Zj2

Comment: if anyone stumbles upon a similar problem, i'd suggest switching to *.scala based full definition, it's far easier to comprehend the build when it's in one place

Comment: Absolutely true, I've fixed the problem just using one .scala definition on the root project. Thanks @OlegYch for your recommendation.